# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{x+2^n}} $ in $(-2,\infty)$ uniformly convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

> Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{x+2^n}} $ in $(-2,\infty)$ uniformly convergent?

I started by checking if it is pointwise convergent, because if it wasn't then especially it is not uniformly conveergent. But by Leibnitz, it is convergent.

But I got stuck on proving that it is uniformly convergent. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the fact that the absolute value of each term is smaller than $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ should lead to what you are looking for.

Comment: @Ali: I agree, except it is really every term after the first.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Oops, I missed that tiny initial term :)

Comment: Try to use this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405087/is-sum-n-1-infty-x2-e-nx-uniformly-convergent-in-0-infty).

Answer (score 1):

Also a hint: Set $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{x+2^{n}}$. Now consider sequences $x_{k}=-2+\frac{1}{2^{k}}$ and $y_{k}=-2+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$. Obviously $|x_{k}-y_{k}|\to 0$  when $k\to\infty$. Now see what happens with $|f(x_{k})-f(y_{k})|=|x_{k}-y_{k}||\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(x_{k}+2^{n})(y_{k}+2^{n})}|$. More precisely, consider the first term in summation...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use Weierstrass M-test with $$ M_n = \frac{1}{2^n-2}.$$

Comment: Did you notice that the domain is $(-2,\infty)$?

Comment: Jonas, if the domain is $(-2,\infty)$ then perhaps:
$|\frac{(-1)^n}{x+2^n}| \leq |\frac{1}{x+2^n}| \leq |\frac{1}{2^n - 2}|$?

Comment: @TheNotMe: That's right. Of course, the first term is unbounded, but that isn't relevant for convergence.  Just throw out the first term to apply the test.  (Interesting that now the bound in this hint was first in the OP's comment.)

Comment: But does this $M_n$ converge? I wasn't able to prove that it converges to be honest!

Comment: On other thoughts, by the ***ratio test*** we get $L=0$ which means it converges.
Correct?