# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {x^2 e^{-nx}}$ uniformly convergent in $[0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {x^2 e^{-nx}}$ uniformly convergent in $[0,\infty)$?

So I started by saying that by the geometric series test where $a=x^2$ and $|r| = |\frac{1}{e^x}| \leq 1$, the series converges pointwise.

But how do I exactly prove that it converges uniformly? I am quite sure it is by weistrass test but I can not find an upper bound to compare it to! Any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the [M-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test)?

Comment: As I said in my original post that I was sure it was by the weistrass $M$ test. but all I get is that $\frac{x^2}{e^{nx}} \leq \frac{x^2}{e^x}$, but that almost gives me nothing (I think, at least.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let
$$f_n(x)=x^2e^{-nx}$$
then we have
$$f'_n(x)=e^{-nx}\left(2x-nx^2\right)=0\iff x=0\ \text{or}\ x=\frac{2}{n}$$
so 
$$||f_n||_\infty=f_n\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)=\frac{4}{n^2}e^{-2}$$
hence the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty ||f_n||_\infty$ is convergent and then the series  $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ is uniformly convergent.

Comment: Clear and easily understandable. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane, You used the M-test, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the remainder term explicitly, using the formula for the geometric series:
$$ r_N(x) = \sum_{n=N}^\infty x^2 e^{-nx} = x^2e^{-Nx} \sum_{j = 0}^\infty e^{-jx} =   \dots
$$
Now find the maximum of $r_N$ on $[0, \infty)$. (It's obviously a positive function.)

If this maximum tends to $0$ as $N \to \infty$, then the convergence is uniform. Otherwise it isn't.